# How to use conditional operator inside validations in vuelidate?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I just installed [vuelidate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuelidate), and created a helper that checks if the value is `phone no`. [reference](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-list-of-helpers)

```
import { helpers } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
const phone = helpers.regex('alpha', /^(09)[0-9]{9}/);
```

My objective is, the input box should accept only `email` or `phone_no`, I tried the solution(s) below but none works.

**Sol. 1**

```
validations: { username: { valid: phone or email }}
```

**Sol. 2**

```
validations: { username: { valid: phone || email }}
```

---

Someone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohws I've figured out the solution!

You need first to import the `or` (your case) or `and`

```
import { email, or, and } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
```

Lastly, *your mistake is*, **You should use it as a function**. Instead of the solutions above, it should be these codes below.

```
validations: { username: { valid: or(email, phone) }}
```