# How do I check two regex values with vuelidate

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm trying to validate an input field with vuelidate. I need it to return valid if either of the following regular expressions is true.

```
const val1 = helpers.regex('val1', /^\D*7(\D*\d){12}\D*$/)
const val2 = helpers.regex('val2', /^\D*1(\D*\d){11}\D*$/)

 const checkvals = () => {
  if(val1 || val2) {
      return true
  } else{
      return false
  }
}
```

Validation

```
numbercheck: {
      required,
      checkvals
    },
```

How do I get this to work?

**Solution**

```
import { or, helpers, required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

    const val1 = helpers.regex('val1', /^\D*7(\D*\d){12}\D*$/)
    const val2 = helpers.regex('val2', /^\D*1(\D*\d)11}\D*$/)


    checkvals: {
      numbercheck,
      valid: or(val1, val2) 
    },
```

**Solution 2**

```
const numbercheck = helpers.regex("mob", /^\D*(?:7(?:\D*\d){12}|1(?:\D*\d)11})\D*$/);
```

Validation

```
checkvals: {
      required,
      numeric,
      numbercheck,
    },
```

Comment: here is [vuelidate documentation](https://vuelidate.js.org/#getting-started) - see if that helps

Comment: or perhaps [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866820/how-to-use-conditional-operator-inside-validations-in-vuelidate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a conditional operator, you could also use a single pattern by placing `7(\D*\d){12}` and `1(\D*\d)11}` in an alternation, as the start and the end of the pattern are the same.

If you don't need the value of the capturing group afterwards, you can turn it in to a non capturing one using `(?:`

I suspect that in the second part, this `11}` should be a quantifier like `{11}`

The pattern could look like:

```
^\D*(?:7(?:\D*\d){12}|1(?:\D*\d){11})\D*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^\D*` Start of string and match 0+ non digits
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `7(?:\D*\d){12}` Match `7` and 12 digits separated by optional non digits
  - `|` Or
  - `1(?:\D*\d){11}` Match `1` and 11 digits separated by optional non digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\D*$` Match optional non digits and assert the end of the string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQX1Ki/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is an old answer but with the latest `@vuelidate/validators: 2.0.4` we no longer need to import it from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'. It throws

> Failed to resolve import "vuelidate/lib/validators"

You can import it as such

```
import { helpers } from "@vuelidate/validators";
```

Hope this helps someone.